# My images won't load on my website

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I've made this wedding website from scratch using html, css, and jquery:

www.benandkim.net

For some reason the images keep failing to load. I will make a few arbitrary tweaks to the html doc and then they will reappear. I will reload it to my ftp and then sure enough a few days later the same bug occurs where none of the images show up OR they show up for one sec and disappear. I'm thinking it is a bug in my slide show?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

~Kim

Comment: First step would be to fix the insane amount of javascript errors. Check your console.

Answer (score 2):

All of your images have `opacity:0;` set

press F12 on chrome and go to the elements panel to see this

Comment: I am not seeing it. Where in the code is that set? Can you see it in firebug?

Comment: Yes, find the images in firebug and you will see it, its more than likely a javascript problem though

Comment: Okay the weird thing is that I don't see opacity in any of my css or html files???

Comment: That's why i said its most probably a JavaScript error that is causing this, maybe i noticed you have some image plugins like fancy-box, i think. fix the JavaScript errors, and it would most likely fix the images

Answer (score 1):

You have opacity set to 0 in your style.  That makes the image totally transparent.

Comment: Oh wow...thanks...must have been a typo!

Comment: The weird thing is that I find the opacity in any of my css or html files

Answer (score 0):

here is your problem you are setting images to opacity 0 in all img tags.

```
<img src=​"images/​hearts.png" alt=​"Hearts" style=​"opacity:​ 0;​ visibility:​ visible;​" class>
```

you need to remove it and then you pictures will appear